# error with deployed Grails app using h2 file DB

Tags: tomcat, grails, h2

I want to have a stand alone package including Tomcat and my Grails 2.5 app with a h2 DB file.
in Config.groovy I set to load properties files

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:mytool-config.properties"]
```

in mytool-config.properties I have:

```
dataSource.username = "sa"
dataSource.password = "db!admin"
dataSource.url = "jdbc:h2:file:E:\\MyTool\\db\\MyTool;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
```

Folder E:\MyTool\db exists of course. Also tried to place an already created MyTool.h2.db file.

my DataSources.groovy looks like:

```
dataSource {
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    pooled = true
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            logSql = false
        }
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = false
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"             
            logSql = false
        }
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
    }
}
```

But starting the tomcat service the app does not work tomcat7-stdout.2016-02-09.log I get:

```
2016-02-09 11:59:35,797 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.h2.Driver@3871b7bc returned null for URL:"jdbc:h2:file:E:\MyTool\db\MyTool;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
```

It works fine in my development machine with run-app. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by removing the " and spaces from the properties file mytool-config.properties. Stupid common mistake.

```
dataSource.username=sa
dataSource.password=db!admin
ataSource.url=jdbc:h2:file:E:\\MyTool\\db\\MyTool;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
```